# Video doesn't start playing anymore

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, gsap

I'm creating a website for which I have to click a button to make a video open. It used to work, but now it doesn't anymore. Did I accidentally delete or change something?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```js
textbela.style.opacity=0;
av1.onmouseover = function(){
  TweenMax.to (textbela,0.69,{opacity:1})
  TweenMax.to (vid1,0.66,{height:"100%"})
}

av1.onmouseout = function(){
  TweenMax.to (textbela,0.69,{opacity:0})
  TweenMax.to (vid1,1,{height:"10%"})
}

av1.onclick = function(){
  TweenMax.to ($(".button"),1,{opacity:0,onComplete:fct})
  function fct (){
    vid.style.display="block"
    vid.play();
  }
}
```

```css
#av1{
  position:absolute;
  left:5%;
  background:url(previews/av1.jpg) 70% 50%;
  background-size:cover;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #000;
}

#vid1{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

#vid1 p{
  color:#F3EBEB;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:0px;
}

#vid {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  height:90%;
  width:100%;
}

#av1:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#av1:hover #textbela{
  color: white;
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  transition: 0.69s;
}

#textbela{
  font-family: avenir light;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<video id="vid">
  <source src="Bela Lugosi's Dead.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div class="button">
    <div id="av1">
        <div id="vid1">
            <p>Bela Lugosi's Dead</p>
            <div id="textbela">J’ai réalisé le clip de la chanson “Bela Lugosi’s Dead”  de Bauhaus. La chanson parle de Bela Lugosi, l’acteur ayant incarné Dracula pour la première fois dans le film de 1931.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"Did I accidentally delete or change something?" All signs point to "yes".

(You never define 'vid' in your `av1.onclick`; likely you used to have a `var vid = $('#vid')` in there.)